# Show that $f$ is a continuous function

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity

The function $d: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ given by $d(x,y):=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$ defines a metric on $\mathbb{R}$. The usual metric is given by $d_{st}(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Furthermore, $f: (\mathbb{R},d) \to (\mathbb{R}, d_{st})$ is a function given by $f(x)=x$. Prove that $f$ is a continous function.

---

So by definition we have that $f$ is continous in a point $y$ if for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ so that $d_{st}(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ if $d(x,y)<\delta$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta=\min\{2,\epsilon\}$. Pick $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ at random and assume $d(x,y)<\delta$.

We then get:

$d_{st}(f(x),f(y))=d_{st}(x,y)=|x-y|$.

I want to state now that $|x-y|\leq d(x,y)<\delta=\epsilon$ but that doesn't hold when $|x-y|>1$, does it?

I don't know what to do now. I would appreciate if somebody could help me out!

Comment: where did you use the 2? why did you pick the 2?

Comment: @DavidP I figured $d(x,y)$ could equal $1$ at most if $|x-y|<1$, so I picked a random integer larger than $1$ to cover for those values.

Comment: The two topologies coincide, so that identity is trivially continuous.

Comment: @Crostul Could you point out what I'm doing wrong in my proof?

Comment: @trix I don't get where does $\delta = \min \{ \mathbf{2} , \epsilon \}$ come from. Why $2$? Why not $0.5$ (which is, and here is the point, smaller than $1$)?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the $d_{st}$ metric is to make the normal metric $d(x,y)$ bounded. But you can ignore their difference by looking at the set of points with $d(x,y) < 1$, so that $d_{st}(x,y) = d(x,y)$. Thus, in your proof, insist that $\delta < 1$. Then you can take any $\delta < \epsilon$ so that $d(x,y) < \delta \implies d_{st}(x,y) = d(x,y) < \delta < \epsilon$.

The moral here is that these two metrics are same on a small scale, which is all that matters for continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to prove that is uniformly continuous. The value of $\delta$ depends of the value of $\epsilon$ but also the value of $y$.